# Send Arraylist as value of json object?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I want to send json object as post parameter to php script. but i want to send it as this format shown below

```
{"people_ids":[118, 120],"userAdding":"123"}
```

so i can convert value of people_ids into php array.

```
$peopleIDsArray = $json['people_ids'];
```

But when I do this, it print json object as shown below.

```
JSONObject jsonOBJ = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonOBJ.put("userAdding", user._id);
            jsonOBJ.put("people_ids", Arrays.toString(peopleIds.toArray()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

// array as string. (JSON OBJECT )

```
{"person_ids":"[118, 120]","user_id":"123"}
```

is there any way, i can achieve the above format??

Comment: Where is `group_id` coming from? The mistake is not in the part you have posted.

Comment: Thank for your time @Subir.. i have updated the question !!

But Hariharan reply is what i was looking for !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.. if `peopleIds` is **ArrayList**

```
    JSONObject jsonOBJ = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonOBJ.put("userAdding", user._id);
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray(peopleIds);
        jsonOBJ.put("people_ids", list);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How can I send this json array to java script code as var. I need retrive that json list in my java script code like var people=list;   (JSONArray type).

Answer (score 0):

Very easy way to send an array to JSON

```
 ArrayList<Model> arrayList = ArrayList()    
JSONObject jsonOBJ = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonOBJ.put("userAdding", arrayList.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```